# How to assign fields to each tab in WP Gutenberg TabPanel

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I know it's a simple question, but I am new in the React and WP Gutenberg world.
I am trying to create a plugin settings page using Gutenberg Components.

The tabs working fine and i know how to render fields, but i can't figure out how to assign to each tab the fields i want.

Here is the sample code:

```
import { TabPanel } from '@wordpress/components';
 
const onSelect = ( tabName ) => {
    console.log( 'Selecting tab', tabName );
};
 
const MyTabPanel = () => (
    <TabPanel
        className="my-tab-panel"
        activeClass="active-tab"
        onSelect={ onSelect }
        tabs={ [
            {
                name: 'tab1',
                title: 'Tab 1',
                className: 'tab-one',
            },
            {
                name: 'tab2',
                title: 'Tab 2',
                className: 'tab-two',
            },
        ] }
    >
        { ( tab ) => <p>{ tab.title }</p> }
    </TabPanel>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Developer guide for [Tab Panel](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/tab-panel/#tabs) mentions that
`tabs` is an array of *objects*, which new properties can be added to. By adding a new property, eg `content` to each of your tab objects, additional components can be set to render for each tab. The simple example uses `( tab ) => <p>{ tab.title }</p>` but this could also include your own custom/existing components defined in `content`, eg:

```
import { Button, TabPanel } from '@wordpress/components';

const onSelect = (tabName) => {
    console.log('Selecting tab', tabName);
};

const MyTabPanel = () => (
    <TabPanel
        className="my-tab-panel"
        activeClass="active-tab"
        onSelect={onSelect}
        tabs={[
            {
                name: 'tab1',
                title: 'Tab 1',
                className: 'tab-one',
                content: <p>Some content goes here</p>
            },
            {
                name: 'tab2',
                title: 'Tab 2',
                className: 'tab-two',
                content: <MyCustomComponent />
            },
        ]}
    >
        {({ title, content, className }) => <div className={className}><h3>{title}</h3>{content}</div>}
    </TabPanel>
);

const MyCustomComponent = () => {
    return <><p>Here is a button</p><Button variant="secondary">Click me!</Button></>;
}
```

The [children](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/tab-panel/#children) function (*given as anonymous function, above* `</TabPanel>`) renders the tabviews by passing in the active tab object, which now includes the extra content for the tab. The output of the example above is:
[image: Tabs Example output]

Aside from the Developer Guide, the [Gutenberg source code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/search?q=tabpanel) is a good place to look for other examples of how TabPanel component can be implemented.. Hope this helps you with adding fields to your tabs..